# combine two queries involving count()

Tags: mysql

I have two queries which take data from the same table. Both give me the desired result, but I need to combine them.

```
SELECT H.*, MONTH(`Date`) AS Month FROM `table 1` H INNER JOIN (SELECT `Account ID`, MIN(`Date`) As first_occurence FROM `table 1` GROUP BY `Account ID`) X ON H.`Account ID` = X.`Account ID` AND H.`Date` = X.first_occurence
```

And

```
SELECT H.`Order ID`, H.`Date`, H.`Product`, H.`Amount`, H.`Currency`, MONTH(`Date`) AS Month, COUNT(`Account ID`) AS Number_subs
FROM `table 1` H GROUP BY `Account ID`;
```

I basically would like to have the column `COUNT(Account ID) AS Number_subs` as part of the result of the first query. My idea was to use the second one as subquery of the first one, but it resulted in an error (too many returned rows).
Has anybody an idea how to easily implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate your count in your first query as

```
SELECT H.*, 
    MONTH(`Date`) AS Month ,
    X.Number_subs
FROM `table 1` H 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `Account ID`, 
        MIN(`Date`) As first_occurence ,
        COUNT(`Account ID`) AS Number_subs
    FROM `table 1` 
    GROUP BY `Account ID`
) X ON H.`Account ID` = X.`Account ID` AND H.`Date` = X.first_occurence
```